# Can a routine know the unit where it runs?

Tags: delphi

Can a function/procedure know the unit/module where it runs (and maybe write it down to a text file)?
I know that there is a lot of debug info in the DCU/EXE file, including the association between the executable code and the source/pas code. Could it be accessed from inside the routine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a plain function or procedure, but a class knows the unit it is declared in. Therefore any method can get that from the `UnitName` class function.

You can make use of this even in a plain function or procedure in that unit, when you take any class declared in that unit and call `TWhatEverClass.UnitName`.

If there is no class declared in that unit you can declare one dummy class just for this purpose.

Comment: This exists since which Delphi version?

Comment: Wow. Just Wow!!

Comment: @AmigoJack, Delphi 2009 IIRC

Comment: @UweRaabe you remembered correctly, it was introduced with Delphi 2009.